# COUNTIFS is showing wrong output in Sorted data

Tags: excel-formula

COUNTIF is showing wrong output in the sorted data:

POOJA YADAV

---

PRAKASH SINHA

---

PRATIBHA

---

PRATIBHA

---

PRATIBHA

---

PRATIBHA

---

PRATIBHA

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

PREETI PRAJAPATI

---

RAJENDRA SAHU

---

In the above example the code should return '5' when searching 'PRATIBHA', but

it shows '4'.
If I change the name of 'PRATIBHA' to 'PRATIBHA TANDI', it shows '5'.

Why is this happening?

Help

=COUNTIFS($N$2:$N$211,N166)

Answer (score 0):

You could have an extra space in one cell, meaning that if you are telling Excel to look for "PRATIBHA" but it finds "PRATIBHA ", it would only return the 4 instead of 5 you know are there. I'd check the data to see if there are any inconsistencies.

Comment: Well I have checked, there is no extra space.